# Change date from 12-31-2015 into 31-Dec-15

Tags: datetime, date, closedate

How can I change the format of the date from the format of 12-31-2015 into the format of 31-Dec-15? Is this even possible in salesforce? As much as possible I want to avoid coding. Thanks in advance. Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: where do you want this change ?on VF?

Comment: no. is there a way in the settings?

Comment: It depends on your locale in User record

Comment: what locale should I use to have this kind of format?

Comment: see http://www.interactiveties.com/b_locale_datetime.php#.VjgMR7erSHs for locale to format master list